# Binominal expression simplification

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I need to simplify the expression

$$\sum_{k = 1}^{10} k\binom{10}{k}\binom{20}{10 - k}$$

Thank you.

Comment: Simplify or evaluate? http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+k*C%2810%2Ck%29*C%2820%2C10-k%29+k%3D1..10

Comment: $$k\binom nk=n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^{10}k\binom{10}k\binom{20}{10-k} =10\sum_{k=1}^{10}k\binom9{k-1}\binom{20}{10-k}$$  and use http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1630679/this-sigma-to-binom/1630708#1630708

Comment: The answer should be 10 x (29 choose 9) .. I can't see how can I get to it from what you wrote. Can you guide me through with a little more explainations?

Comment: It is better to type the problem than to show an image of the problem since images are not searchable.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{10}k\binom{10}{k}\binom{20}{10-k}=10\sum_{k=1}^{10}\binom{9}{k-1}\binom{20}{10-k}=10\sum_{k=0}^{9}\binom{9}{k}\binom{20}{9-k}=10\binom{29}{9}$$

The last equality is [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity).

Comment: Thank you drhab, and from where does the first equality came from?

Comment: $k\binom{10}{k}=\frac{10!}{(k-1)!(10-k)!}=10\frac{9!}{(k-1)!(10-k)!}=10\binom9{k-1}$